# Minimum measure for שריטה/גדידה

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements

I was learning about cutting/scratching. This is a pagan practice of cutting oneself in mourning, and is [forbidden in the Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.14.1?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=en&aliyot=1).

The halachot for this are in [משנה תורה, הלכות עבודה זרה וחוקות הגויים 12:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.12.13?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=he&with=Deuteronomy&lang2=he) and [שולחן ערוך, יורה דעה
180:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.180.6?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

No measure is given for what counts as a שריטה/גדידה, even though other details are given, and measure is given for other halachot in this siman, such as קרחה.

Rambam always gives a measure, and where he doesn't (like with this), you can be sure that there is no minimum measure. However, there are exceptions to every rule so I thought I'd ask if anyone is aware of a minimum measure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a rather enigmatic [Tosefta](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Makkot.3.8) that seems to require that it be visible:

> וכמה ישרוט ויהא חייב כדי שיראה משם שריטה

But the [Ritva](https://www.sefaria.org/Ritva_on_Makkot.21a.1) directly states there's no minimum:

> ומדלא יהיב תלמודא שיעורא לשריטה ש"מ שהיא בכל שהוא

Comment: Not a contradiction. No minimum except until it's visible